# LWJGL - Xbox 360 controller triggers

Tags: java, triggers, controller, lwjgl, xbox

The 2 triggers of xbox controller are in only one axe. No problem, but how can i know id trigger 1 and trigger 2 are pressed in the same time? The value is 0, as when i don't press anything.

Comment: Are you using Legacy LWJGL or LWJGL 3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading controller triggers individually with LWJGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222795/reading-controller-triggers-individually-with-lwjgl)

Answer (score 0):

This answer: [Reading controller triggers individually with LWJGL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24222795/5245373) suggests using XInput library to get individual inputs for each trigger then you could check those instead of both at once. I found a java binding at https://github.com/StrikerX3/JXInput.